# How to switch visibility of an HTML div in css for overlaying

Tags: css

I have a problem with div overlaying system using JS and CSS. Actually i want the div to be triggered as soon as a button is clicked, and want to have a kinda exit button in the div itself, so that pressing it the div goes invisible again as it was at first. I here use JS to switch the style, but it works good the first time, but doesn't seem to make div visible the second time.
here is the code

CSS:

```
#overlay {

position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -100px;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
opacity:0.8;
display:none;
border-radius:50px;
z-index: 10; 
outline: 9999px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }
```

And here is the JS code i use to make it visible, but it works only once.

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block';" style="color:red;">Notify me when you get online</button><p>
```

And this makes it vamoose again.

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.visibility='hidden';" style="background:black; color:white; border-radius:0px;">[ X ]</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display and visibility are not the same operation. To get your code to work, you will need to use one or the other. The `display` property is preferable in this case because it causes the div to be removed completely from the flow, instead of just hidden.

To fix your code, change this:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.visibility='hidden';"
```

to this:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';"
```

For reference, the opposite of `visibility: hidden` is `visibility: visible`, and the opposite of `display: none` is any other one of the display properties, for instance `display: block`, `display: inline`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In one case You use `display` and in other `visibility`.

There is two solutions :

1. In `overlay` class add `visibility:hidden;`, instead `display:none;` change to `block`,  and to show `div` use `document.getElementById('overlay').style.visibility='visible':`
2. To hide Your `div` in Your `[x]` button just use `document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';` instead `visibility:hidden` (better option).

Answer (score 0):

That's cause the inverse of  `display:block;`   is not  `visibility:hidden;`

**but** `display: none;`

so in JS it's like `...display = "none"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

<sub>P.S: Don't use inline CSS and JS. Keep styling and logic away from templating</sub>

---

## Simple Overlay popup example using JS and CSS3

The **simplest** and most effective way is to use `visibility` cause than you can **animate** your `#overlay` using CSS3

Here's a quite **awesome** example even with **multiple buttons**:

```js
function toggleOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").classList.toggle("show");
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".overlayBtn"), function( el ){
  el.addEventListener("click", toggleOverlay);
});
```

```css
#overlay{
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

  transition:0.6s;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(0.7);
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
#overlay.show{
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
}
#overlay .overlayBtn{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:2em;
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  right:5px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <a class="overlayBtn">&times;</a>
  Hay yo!
</div>

<button class="overlayBtn">Show</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid facilis doloremque modi alias eveniet temporibus earum distinctio similique veritatis, ratione reprehenderit architecto voluptatibus soluta possimus minus molestias vitae velit est.</p>

<button class="overlayBtn">Show</button>
<p>Eveniet, ut! Facere repellendus cum minima alias laboriosam pariatur nulla laborum magni adipisci error quo accusantium amet fugit soluta nemo, consectetur, ut asperiores ipsum voluptatum commodi rerum, ab repellat. Alias?</p>
```